# antd tree table can't expand rows by default

Tags: reactjs, antd, treetable

I am using antd tree table component version 3 and axios to get api. In documentation to expand rows by default only use defaultExpandAllRows but it doesn't work when i using api to get data
here my code https://codesandbox.io/s/so-56598439-522fu

it can like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q8FB.png)
but i want by default like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaETx.png)

========================================================================
after fetch its work. thanks Manish Sundriyal

Comment: It is not expanding because the data is not yet fetched. This means at the time of rendering there is no data source passed to the Table component. Now once your data is fetched the component will not re-render itself.

Comment: thanks, after fetch its work

Comment: no problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an answer in 2023, you can use the expandable prop and set expandedRowKeys to match with the rows you want to open

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-tree-data-default-async-expand-bjsq88)

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question and welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be awesome if you added a little code example to your answer :)

Comment: Added an example via codesandbox